# Python pygments, Tkinter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, tkinter, tokens

Ayuda no funciona el `token string`, estoy creando un editor de código, pero cuando creo el resaltado de sintaxis los `strings` quedan en negro.

```
def syn(self,event=None):
    self.campotexto.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
    self.data = self.campotexto.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    for token, content in lex(self.data, PythonLexer()):
        self.campotexto.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" %len(content))
        self.campotexto.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
        self.campotexto.mark_set("range_start", "range_end") 
        self.campotexto.tag_configure("Token.Keyword",foreground="orangered")
        self.campotexto.tag_configure("Token.String", foreground="red")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio el problema es que usas el nombre incorrecto del token en `tag_configure`, para los literales de cadena es `Token.Literal.String`, no `Token.String`, un pequeño ejemplo usando un widget `tkinter.Text`:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

from pygments import lex
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer

root = tk.Tk()
campotexto = tk.Text(root)

# Parse the code and insert into the widget
def syn(self,event=None):
    campotexto.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
    data = campotexto.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
        campotexto.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" %len(content))
        campotexto.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
        campotexto.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")
        campotexto.tag_configure("Token.Text", foreground="black")
        campotexto.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String.Single", foreground="red")
        campotexto.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String.Double", foreground="green")
        campotexto.tag_configure("Token.Literal.String.Doc", foreground="blue")


campotexto.pack()
root.bind("<Key>", syn)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! si me sivio, sabes como puedo hacer para pintar los self de las clases de verde por ejemplo? y las variables?

Comment: @LucasBagnasco `self` si no me equivoco está tokenizado como `"Token.Name.Builtin.Pseudo"` junto a `None`, `Ellipsis`, `False`, `True`, y `NotImplemented`. Los nombres (identificadores) de las variables creo que son `"Token.Name"`